# How to get the twitter picture of a user?

Tags: twitter

I am making a website in which people put in a twitter username. Now I want to load the twitterimage of the name that is put in. I have searched on the internet already but can't find a good easy way to implement this. Do i need to use some fancy twitter api or something? Any simple API's? (it is only for a simple site) or URL's with name as variable in it?

Comment: i am using php and jquery, do you mean that?

Comment: Ah yes, it needs to work in a javascript function, so the answer mentioned by adt doesn't work unfortunatly. any other ideas?

Comment: i tried below solution  entered username in textbox and click  GeImage link it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function GetImage(){

        var txtBox = document.getElementById("twit");
        var imgTwitter = document.getElementById("imgTwitter");
        imgTwitter.src = "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/" + txtBox.value;

    }


    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <input name="twit" id="twit" type="text"><a href="#" onclick="javascript:GetImage();">Get Image</a>


    <img id="imgTwitter"  >

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I found that tut, btu it wasn't working, and also you solution doesn't work since i need to be able to use it within javascript, so when I do it like that it doesn;t work, because there is some redirect. Any other ideas?

Answer (score -1):

From this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30322178/6539400

```
https://twitter.com/[screen_name]/profile_image?size=mini
https://twitter.com/[screen_name]/profile_image?size=normal
https://twitter.com/[screen_name]/profile_image?size=bigger
https://twitter.com/[screen_name]/profile_image?size=original
```

```js
function ClickFunction() {
 document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "";

 var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
 var uname = document.getElementById("name").value;

 var SRCmini = "https://twitter.com/" + uname + "/profile_image?size=mini";
 var SRCnormal = "https://twitter.com/" + uname + "/profile_image?size=normal";
 var SRCbigger = "https://twitter.com/" + uname + "/profile_image?size=bigger";
 var SRCoriginal = "https://twitter.com/" + uname + "/profile_image?size=original";

 frag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(SRCmini));
 frag.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
 var IMGmini = frag.appendChild(document.createElement("img"));
  IMGmini.src = SRCmini;
 frag.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

 frag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(SRCnormal));
 frag.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
 var IMGnormal = frag.appendChild(document.createElement("img"));
  IMGnormal.src = SRCnormal;
 frag.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

 frag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(SRCbigger));
 frag.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
 var IMGbigger = frag.appendChild(document.createElement("img"));
  IMGbigger.src = SRCbigger;
 frag.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

 frag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(SRCoriginal));
 frag.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
 var IMGoriginal = frag.appendChild(document.createElement("img"));
  IMGoriginal.src = SRCoriginal;
 frag.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

 document.getElementById("content").appendChild(frag);
}
```

```html
<input id="name" value="wikipedia" /><br />
<button onclick="ClickFunction()">Click here!</button><br /><br />


<div id="content"></div>
```