# Handle Twitter / Facebook Authentication in App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter

I want users of my app to be able to authenticate with Twitter and Facebook. This way I know they are a real user. Once they've authenticated once I don't want to have to worry about them logging out or re-authenticating unless they explicitly do so.

I'm storing/displaying the users avatar image. How might I handle if the user were to update this on their given platform? My stored image URL will now be out of date correct? User would essentially have to logoff and re-authenticate in order to have their data updated which isn't ideal...

Comment: Facebook provides a URL that will _redirect_ to the user’s current profile picture (go see docs for the `user` object) – so if you want to display the profile picture in f.e. a web page, you can just use that URL. / Not sure if twitter has something similar – go check their docs.

Comment: I have that working for Facebook. Found this for Twitter: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30322178/20446 Thanks!