# How to get image url for specific twitter status - Twitter API

Tags: image, url, twitter, request

I've seen from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381710/building-twitter-profile-image-url-with-twitter-user-id) post that you can get a user profile image from any of these:

```
https://twitter.com/[screen_name]/profile_image?size=mini
https://twitter.com/[screen_name]/profile_image?size=normal
https://twitter.com/[screen_name]/profile_image?size=bigger
https://twitter.com/[screen_name]/profile_image?size=original
```

And that redirects to an image, which works fine. I'm trying to similarly get the image from a status of form

```
https://twitter.com/[screen_name]/status/894610590915641345/photo/1
```

This doesn't redirect to anything, and neither does this:

```
https://twitter.com/[screen_name]/status/894610590915641345/photo/1?size=original
```

Searching Twitter API brings up only their libraries. Is there a URL to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no shortcut URL to get the images attached to a Tweet. You'll need to retrieve the Tweet via the API, and then extract the media URLs from the JSON response. Use the `statuses/lookup` endpoint to get a Tweet by ID.

I'd also suggest using the API to get the user profile image, as the shortcut URL you mention is not officially supported, does not work on mobile, and may be removed in future. Use the `users/show` endpoint to retrieve a user by screen_name.